# IndexError: tuple index out of range when sorting a list with multiple items by the third item in Python

Tags: python

```
def solver(puzzle_):
        puzzle_so_far = [x for x in puzzle_]
        unsolved = {}
        
        for row in range(9):
            for column in range(9):

                if puzzle_so_far[row][column] == 0:

                    lot = purify(gather_square([row,column]) + puzzle_so_far[row] + [x[column] for x in puzzle_so_far])
                    unsolved[(row,column)]= lot
        
        unsolved = [x for x in unsolved.items()]

        for x in unsolved:
            
            solutions = [[y for y in range(1,10) if y not in x[1]], x[0], len(list(y for y in range(1,10) if y not in x[1]))]
            solutions.sort(key= lambda v : v[2])
            print(solutions)
            
        
        if unsolved == []:
            return puzzle_so_far
    return solver(puzzle)
```

I'm trying to figure out my own sudoku solver, and I'm sure what I'm doing is the opposite of optimal but for now I'd just like to know why

> solutions.sort(key= lambda v : v[2])

gives me the error IndexError: tuple index out of range even though the third item is not a tuple but an integer, all entries of solutions have the format of

```
[[3, 5, 7, 9], (0, 0), 4]
[[4, 5, 7, 9], (0, 1), 4]
[[2, 3, 4], (0, 4), 3]
[[3, 4, 7], (0, 5), 3]
```

and so on. v[0] and v[1] tell me that it cant iterate over integers, which likely means that it is  working on the tuples instead of the whole list, but I dont understand why or how to try and sort the list. Thank you in advance

Comment: Please provide a [mre] and always include the *complete* error traceback in your question. I suggest that you check your data (just print it, for example) before sorting it or when an error occurs during the sort, it probably doesn't look like what you expect at this point.

Comment: In this case it appears that `v` is not `[[3, 5, 7, 9], (0, 0), 4]`, rather `v` is `(0,0)`. So `v[0]` is `0`, `v[1]` is `0`, and `v[2]` doesn't exist, because the tuple indices are only `0` or `1`

Comment: You need the three values to make the tuple in the list comprehension: `[y, x[0], length for y in range(1,10) ...]`, where `length` is as you've calculated from `x[1]`. I'd extract to a function to make it more readable.